# Aligning baseline of two text views in Android

Tags: android, textview

please find below my layout & its result ; I need the text '**Text message**' to align on the baseline of the text '**Header**'(Please find below the code and snapshot). Would be glad if someone can give me direction

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1.0"
android:baselineAligned="true"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:background="@color/custom_orange"
    android:gravity="center"
    >


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Header"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/custom_red"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Text message"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:id="@+id/language"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/custom_green"/> 
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the result

[image]

This is what I need

[image]

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use RelativeLayout as a container for TextViews and add the attribute

```
android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/title"
```

to **id/language** TextView

Answer (score 7):

For **`ConstraintLayout`** just use this↓ to align to another `textView` baseline:

```
app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/textView"
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use the   android:gravity="bottom" on LinearLayout(The linear with the both textviews) and  android:layout_height="wrap_content" in both TextViews.

Comment: Actually it does. I was so surprised when I accidentally find out this. Now I'm trying understand HOW.

Comment: I know this is really old, but I'll just leave this here because I think it's helpful, LinearLayouts have a property called "baselineAligned" (turned on by default) which does exactly what it's name implies: Aligns the Views based on their baselines (pretty much every TextView subclass) unless they have a gravity, which is why OP's layout didn't work correctly. See more here: https://possiblemobile.com/2013/10/shifty-baseline-alignment/

Comment: @JonathanHernández thanks for leaving the comment and the link, it was really helpful indeed!

Answer (score 1):

On Component tree select both component you want to be in same base, right click and then select show baseline. Just drag baseline of two components.