# Android - Align different font-sizes on same baseline

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-xml

I have 2 adjacent `TextView`s, each with a different string that has a different font size. I want the text to have the same baseline in each `TextView`. How can I do this?

Here is my layout:

```
   <LinearLayout
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:background="@color/colorAccentLight"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:text="30"
        />
        <TextView
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:text="hello"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
        />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Here is the current behavior, notice how the 2 `TextView`s have different baselines (the "hello" is lower than the 30) because the font for each `TextView` is a different size.

[image]

Comment: Can't write comments yet. Did you look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26822876/aligning-baseline-of-two-text-views-in-android)?

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using this solution (wrapping both `TextView`s in a `RelativeLayout` and using the "align_baseline" attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the height of both `TextView` elements to `wrap_content`. By default, a horizontal `LinearLayout` will automatically align the baseline of TextView children.

If you're currently using `match_parent` for height in order to have a full-height background color, you'll have to think of a different way to accomplish that. You could, perhaps, use a background color on the `LinearLayout` and then only specify a background color on the larger `TextView`; this will give the same effect you have today.

Answer (score 11):

In `ConstraintLayout` you can simply use

```
app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/textView1"
```